# Button Not Working on Mobile

Tags: html, css, wordpress, button, mobile

[leishasbakeria.com](http://leishasbakeria.com)

Button in brown box on home page (says YUM!) is not working on mobile. What is blocking it?

(the one in the blue box is, but that is only because I set that whole column as a link in VisualComposer.  When I do it this way, I lose my hover animation for the button)

This is set up in Wordpress with Visual Composer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the `float: none;` rule is blocking your button. But I'm not shure why. It is declared in the following css rule:

```
Inline:1 @media only screen and (max-width: 1000px) .grey-box {
    display: block !important;
    margin: 0 auto !important;
    float: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a tool you use to diagnose issues, or did you just click around till you found the trigger?

Comment: I used the [Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Tools_Toolbox) feature from Firefox and checked which css rule takes the effect